# SQL Server permissions and views

Tags: sql-server, view, permissions

I'm curious if there is a way for a user to use a view in database A (they have permission to database A) that accesses tables in database B (and/or additional databases they don't have permission to) without the user having access to database B?

My scenario:

We currently have a database (database A) where most of the views are housed. Most users across the team also have access to database A. We are wanting to split out our data tables from database A into their own databases (on the same server). When we do this, of course, the views will break because the tables they access will now be in database B. Since there are so many views, I'm looking for an easier way. My thought was to use database A as the hub for the views and as the views are accessed, permissions are granted to the various databases for the user(s) - without giving them direct access to the other databases.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you enable DB_CHAINING in both databases, no permissions on the tables are needed as long as the db owners are the same.  However, users will still need to be granted access to database B (but no other permissions). You could enable the guest users in database B to avoid adding the users to the other database.

Answer (score 0):

I think a database role would be better than a database as the container for view access.

It might be easier to delete objects than to move them.  A backup-restore can create a copy of the database.  Then delete the tables and views that don't belong in each database.

Cutting corners on security or integration can come back to bite.  If the tables are distinctly part of different systems, then the views should go with the tables.  Security and integration between systems by cross database references will tie all those systems to the same server.  (Linked servers would be a performance and DTC nightmare.)  We have several "separate" justice applications (e.g., DA, Public Defender, Probation, etc.) that do this.  Security is still detailed via the use of database roles for each use.  The integration is great, but it's a nightmare to migrate because it's all at once and together.  If done correctly (e.g., connections strings to each database), we would be able to move one database at a time and update and test one system at a time.  As it is now, it takes a lot of project management and a long time to get everybody ready.

If the tables are part of the same system, then schemas could be an option to segregate them if database roles are to tedious to manage.  Is it more work to segregate the objects into databases or schemas than to manage a role?

Also, if you use SSDT db projects, then those cross database references (circular?) can be a pain.

For security, I would suggest a database role for each group that needs access.  There is no "magic" database level container just for views.  The best you can do is SELECT which includes tables and views.  For just views, a script is not hard to create to grant a db role select access to all views in the db.  I would not ever use grant select and then a DENY on tables because it can prevent access to table for users that should have access.  If one or more schemas are used for the views, a role can be granted SELECT access to the schema.  This might be the best option.  If the view schema and the objects accessed by the view have the same owner, the ownership chain should allow access via the view to tables.  For example, if the "view" schema is owned by "dbo", views in the "view" schema should be able to access tables in the "dbo" schema without the user being granted access to those tables.  (I have not tried it.)

It would be nice if there was a second flavor of INSERT, UPDATE, etc. permissions that applied to views only, but there isn't.